# Progressbar with a timer

Tags: c#, timer, progress-bar

I have a piece of code which gets the available server instances from my SQL server to DataTable. It will take some time to populate. So I tried to add a progress bar to indicate that time. There are some ways to do that:

1.Using Background worker
2.Using a timer

I used a timer but progress bar is not animating.

my code is(WinForm) :

```
private void frmCodeGenerator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        tmrWaiting.Enabled = true;
        tmrWaiting.Start();

        //List all available servers
        PopulateServerInstances();
        //List all default namespaces to import

        //Set the target folder default path tec.

        tmrWaiting.Stop();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }

private void tmrWaiting_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            pbWaiting.Value++;
        }
```

Cursor is changing form normal to waitstate but progress bar didn't. Am I doing wright?

Comment: Did you set `pbWaiting.Maximum` ?

Comment: Yes. From visual studio property editor. `pbWaiting.Maximum = 100` and `pbWaiting.Visible = true`

Comment: What INTERVAL are you using? If it is too large it may be that it is not firing by the time the task has completed? Also, this will just count up regardless of the actual progress? Is this just dummy code?

Comment: @Belogix I don't think it is likely. By default `Timer.Interval` is set to 100 milliseconds.

Comment: THe problem here is that, when it starts loading the database, it mostly locks the whole window, which does not allow anything else to happen until everything is fully loaded (like your progressbar). I would recommend you to use threading for this, so your progressbar runs while it also fetches the data.

A Good example which I learned by http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: @WeeklyDad Correct. I'll look forward to it. Thanks for the help and the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Load` event handler, which is running on your UI thread, is calling `PopulateServerInstances`, which is presumably blocking whilst loading the data. You need to do that work on a BG thread so that your UI thread can continue to update the UI. [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is your best bet, because it includes support for updating progress information on the UI thread as you go along.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `Load` event handler. I have a Winforms that does most of its work within its `Load` event, and the progress bar in there works just fine (Although the progress bar is being updated in the background thread via a delegate)

Comment: as an additional point, your form will not be shown until populate method completes.

Comment: @Nolonar: that would only make sense if you're periodically calling `Application.DoEvents()` to pump all UI events, or if your handler has somehow been marshalled to another thread.

Comment: Thanks. It was the case. My `Load` event blocks the UI while populating the list. I'll try to implement the code using BG. @ Taner You're correct. My form will not be shown until method completes.

Comment: @KentBoogaart You're right. I totally forgot about my form pushing its work onto another thread, +1 for pointing that out